# SQL Server Management Studio-Добавить Identity в Диаграмме

Tags: sql, sql-server

Накидал модель в диаграмме, хочу присвоить IDENTITY атрибуту таблицы, нигде не могу найти как это сделать, еще и Management Studio на русском языке поставлена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В свойствах столбца параметр Спецификация идентификатора.

Comment: Не нахожу [(Cкриншот)](http://joxi.ru/wRmzvaBTzRgjmO)

Comment: На скриншоте свойства таблицы, а я говорю о свойствах столбца.